# Why is the answer of $sum 6?

Tags: php

```
<?php

$numbers = array(1,2,3,4);

$total = count($numbers);

$sum = 0;

$output = "";

$i = 0;

foreach($numbers as $number) { 
$i = $i + 1;

if ($i < $total) {

    $sum = $sum + $number;

}

}

echo $sum;

?>
```

I'm going through PHP on TeamTreehouse.com, whilst learning php this was one of the quiz question, the answer is 6. I don't know why the answer is 6, can someone explain?

Comment: Write manually on the paper every iteration of the loop to understand what happens to the variables. That's the best way to learn ;)

Comment: Because you increment the `$i` before the if statement

Comment: If you increment the $i, $i becomes 1. 1 is still less than $total in the if statement.

Comment: see https://3v4l.org/E1Lkt

Comment: I just did echo $i; and received 4. Is it incrementing with each number, because for each $numbers as $number passed through, $i +1 for each time it needs to loop? Because to me that would be 8, I don't understand where 6 comes from :(

Comment: @VolkerK So, it's skipping $sum = $sum + $number; because $i = 4 and $total = 4 and just counting the spaces in the array(0, 1 ,2 ,3) = 6?

Comment: Yes, except: "and just counting the spaces" - that I do not understand.

Comment: @VolkerK arrays start from 0 and increment from there. So I thought it might have counted 0, 1, 2, 3 which equals 6. But an answer below has helped me understand even more so, thank you!

Comment: a) In php "arrays" do not necessarily start from 0. b) The foreach loop iterates the values, i.e. 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable $i is initialized by 0 (zero).
**Before** the condition *if ($i < $total)* is tested $i is incremented by 1. So even the first time it equals 1.
In the third pass $i equals 3, and in the fourth pass it equals 4 which is **NOT** < $total.

Therefore only 3 of the 4 elements of $numbers are summed up: 1 + 2 + 3, which equals 6.

See the comments in the code below:

```
<?php

$numbers = array(1,2,3,4);

$total = count($numbers);         // Gives 4

$sum = 0;

$output = "";

$i = 0;                           // $i = 0

foreach($numbers as $number) { 
    $i = $i + 1;                  // $i = 1, even at the first time
                                  // after 3 passes $i is equal to $total (=4)
    if ($i < $total) {            // So, only 3 of the 4 elements of $number are honored
        $sum = $sum + $number;
    }
}

echo $sum;                        // Thus $sum = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6
                                  // The last element (=4) is never summed up

?>
```

This would sum up all 4 elements, giving 10 as the result:

```
foreach($numbers as $number) { 
    if ($i < $total) {
        $sum = $sum + $number;
    }
    $i = $i + 1;
}
```

Comment: Apologies for needing to be spoon-fed, but this is the best explanation. Thank you for your help, I now understand fully!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$numbers = array(1,2,3,4);

$total = count($numbers); #value of $total is 4 here
$sum = 0;
$output = ""; #intital empty
$i = 0;

foreach($numbers as $number) { 
$i = $i + 1;

if ($i < $total) {

    $sum = $sum + $number;

}

}

echo $sum;

?>
```

You increment the $i by 1 so it becomes 1 which is smaller than $total(which is 4). Your program will add till $i become 4. It just add first three number in your array.

> 1+2+3=6.

That's why you are getting 6.
I hope you get it. :)

Answer (score -1):

The condition limits the iterations. When `$i` is 4 it is no longer less than `$total` and so the last number doesn't get added.

Comment: It's not my condition it was a quiz on treehouse to figure out the answer, I got it wrong so I printed the code and it showed 6. I didn't understand WHY it was printing 6. 

So `$i = 4` because it's incremented with each item in the array, so it's no longer less than `$total` they become equal, so it doesn't bother doing the sum.

Does the 6 come from `$numbers = array(0, 1, 2 ,3)` as in the spaces, not actual items. It's counting the spaces so total = 6?

Comment: Because it's adding 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: It stops at three because $i needs to be less than 4, so it doesn't go past 4. So it only does the first 3 numbers in the array which is 1+2+3 = 6. Am I understanding this correct?

Comment: @MikeRodham: Exactly.